# Can 5k users directly approve a tag wiki proposed edit?

Tags: support, tag-wiki, suggested-edits

As 20k user, I can directly approve a tag wiki edit. Do 5k users have that possibility too, or are two 5k users required for approving a tag wiki proposed edit?

Comment: 10Kers can directly approve tag wiki edits too.  I don't think I could before I was 10000.

Comment: [5K users have now access to the review page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105755/roll-out-10k-tools-gradually-between-3k-and-10k-reputation-for-users-who-have-sho/105870#105870). It was not so, before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It takes only one 5k user to approve an edit to a tag wiki or a tag wiki excerpt.